# EnableCollectionSynchronization: is not possible convert from "method groups" to CollectionSychonizationCallback

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, thread-safety

I'm studying Collection editing outside main thread but I've got stuck on this error, visual studio says is not possible convert from "method groups" to CollectionSychonizationCallback. What I'm missing?

```
void ObservableCollectionCallback(ObservableCollection<MyType> collection, object context, Action accessMethod, bool writeAccess)
{
            var collectionLock = (ReaderWriterLockSlim)context;
            Action enterLock = writeAccess ? new Action(collectionLock.EnterWriteLock) : new Action(collectionLock.EnterReadLock);
            Action exitLock = writeAccess ? new Action(collectionLock.ExitWriteLock) : new Action(collectionLock.ExitReadLock);

            enterLock();
            try { accessMethod(); } finally { exitLock(); }
}


ReaderWriterLockSlim valuesLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public Page()
{
       InitializeComponent();
         ...

       BindingBase.EnableCollectionSynchronization(MyObjList, valuesLock,ObservableCollectionCallback );


          ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with contravariance, your concrete method can only accept ["parameters that have less derived types (contravariance) than that specified by the delegate type"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates). In this case, the delegate signature for `ObservableCollectionCallback` expects an `IEnumerable` and you need to change your method signature to fit (get an IEnumerable, cast it inside.)